# 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities with a complex where statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to Linq and hope someone can help me.  I know this question has probable already been answered somewhere but I can't find it so here goes. I am trying to retrieve one record that matches the name of the person.  Here is my code. when I use just one variable in the where statement the code works fine but when there are more than one I get the array index error.  Can anyone please straighten me out on what I am doing wrong.

```
var test = (from b in _context.UserInfos
   where b.FirstName == splitCacId[0] && b.MiddleInitial == splitCacId[1] && b.FirstName == splitCacId[2]
   select b).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's not your intention to filter on `b.FirstName` twice. Or `splitCacId` has less than 3 entries.

Comment: Share the code of how you are initializing the `splitCacId` object.

Comment: I change the last filter to Lastname and still get the same error message. The answer to the next question is             var splitCacId = cardId.Split('.');
to split up the name an that works fine.

Comment: The error indicates you are using LINQ To EF 6.x which does not support array indexing into constants. Put your `splitCacId[]` values in temporary variables and test those instead. Also, why is it `splitCacId` when you are splitting `cardId` and not `splitCardId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an array index (splitCacId[0]) inside an expression tree, it tries to convert that into an expression as well.

Just work around it by using a separate variable

Use following code instead of accessing array index in linq directly.

```
var firstName = splitCacId[0];
var MiddleInitial= splitCacId[1];
var lastName = splitCacId[2];

var test = (from b in _context.UserInfos
   where b.FirstName == firstName && b.MiddleInitial == MiddleInitial && b.FirstName == lastName 
   select b).FirstOrDefault();
```